# Do I need to explicitly add a property int to foreign keys for composed objects using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Do I need to add an integer `PropertyId`, in the example case `UserId`, for every foreign key object using Entity Framework? NHibernate handles this automatically, I'm wondering if there is any way to solve that using just the object and to not retrieving it from the database every time I add a new register.

I tried an insert, just defining :

```
// It's complaining about required user fields
var newMenu = new Menu { Name = "test", User = new User { Id = 1 }};

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how you will write a query to get all menus by user id without such property?

Comment: `menus.Where(m => m.User.Id == 1);`

Comment: Does that mean query for menu will always load and include related User data?

Comment: In that case yes, but even it was not a not null field, I could use `menus.Where(m => m.User?.Id == 1);` with no errors

Answer (score 0):

In EF, you have to explicitly define the foreign key and also use the `ForeignKey` Attribute to specify the relationship

```
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I realized that, but I was wondering if there is any way to use it without an additional int property

Comment: No, I don't think there is anyway to do that in EF

Answer (score 0):

```
//create or retrieve the user that has to be linked to menu from the database
User u = users.Where(user => user.Id == 1); // example

var newMenu1 = new Menu{ Name = "test", User = u };
var newMenu2 = new Menu{ Name = "test2", User = u };
```

Then you can save changes. You use only the user object.
Is that what you needed?